# Issues with using if/else statements correctly in C language

Tags: c, if-statement, nested

I am still very new to programming, so I am not sure the correct action to take. I can't seem to get the program to display a different option when selected by the user. Either the first option displays, or it shows the 'Invalid Entry' text. I am only going to include the problem code, since I've tested the rest without the if/else statements and it calculates and displays correctly.

```
printf("Select interest type: S, Y, M \n\n");
scanf("%ch", &type); /*program has finished calculating and is waiting on user input. Variable 'type' has already been initialized as a char*/

printf("\n\nIn %i years, at %.2f percent interest rate, \n", n, R);

/*this is where the problem starts*/
if (type == 'S')
    printf("Your investment becomes %.2f dollars, with simple interest.\n", futureVal_simp);
else
{
    if (type == 'Y')
        printf("Your investment becomes %.2f dollars, with annual compounding interest.\n", futureVal_yr);
    else
    {
        if (type == 'M')
            printf("Your investment becomes %.2f dollars, with monthly compounding interest.\n\n\n", futureVal_mnth);
        else printf("Invalid entry.\n\n\n"); /*these are supposed to display based on char entered*/
    }
}


return 0;
}
```

I checked other questions on the site, but am still not sure. Should I be using != and && instead of multiple if/else?

Comment: I would most likely use a `switch` statement for this, or at least `else if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already got the answer from Mr **@John Zwinck**, but just for the sake of completeness,

You should change your scanf from

```
 scanf("%ch", &type);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &type);  // note the extra space before %c
```

This tells `scanf()` to ignore all previous whitespace-like charcaters and read the first non-whitespace input.

FYI, in previous case, the previously pressed <kbd>ENTER</kbd> keystroke [after previous input] was stored as a `\n` in the input buffer. Then, that `\n` being a *valid* input for `%c`, was being read by `scanf()`, producing the scenario

> '%c' it doesn't ask for input at all.

Also, as an improvement, you can consider using a switch statement instead of if-else condition.

Comment: And if anyone can please let me know the reason behind the downvote, i'll be glad.

Answer (score 2):

You want `scanf("%c", &type);` not `"%ch"`.  The `%c` means a character, the `h` means a literal `h`.

You also need to check the return value of `scanf()`. Always.

Comment: That's sort of what I thought, but when I change it to '%c'  it doesn't ask for input at all. There's clearly something else going wrong.

Comment: @Nemorov: Then there's still something in the buffer consumed by %c, and with the code in the question, `scanf` simply waits for a literal h. Please provide a complete code example with the exact input in the question.

Comment: @Nemorov I've added a solution to your problem. It was too lengthy to _explain_ as a comment. I had to add a seperate anser for that.  Please try that.

Answer (score 1):

Using logical operator / if-else statement -- if they are equivalent, choosing one of them is your choice. (Maybe in this case, you can also use switch statement.)
But sometimes, using too long logical formula as a condition can reduce the readability of your code.

```
if(type == 'S')
{
    content...
}
else if(type == 'Y')
{...}
else if(type == 'M')
{...}
else{...}
```

Because else if means else{if(...)} as itself, so you don't need to write another if/else statement in else block.

The best way I recommend is to use switch statement in this case. Branch conditions are not complex -- those conditions are just to check out whether the character 'type' is 'S', 'Y', 'M' or others. In this situation, switch statement can increase the readability of your code.

Comment: This is really good suggestions to use switch/case. Char is integer type, and all conditions use ==. Moreover code will be compact and more maintainable.