# Else If statement in C is not executing correctly

Tags: c, if-statement, operators

I wrote a C program for a calculator using else...if statement. There are no syntax errors and it compiles well but the program skips all the conditions and and only executes the last one (displaying the error message). I can't figure out what is wrong. [here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfiAW.png). I'm sorry this if this is a stupid question, i tried googling this but came up with nothing.

code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
{
float no1, no2, ans;
char op;

printf("ENTER 1ST NUMBER:\n");
scanf("%f",&no1);
printf("ENTER 2ND NUMBER:\n");
scanf("%f",&no2);
printf("ENTER A BASIC MATHEMATICAL OPERATOR:\n");
scanf("%ch",&op);

if(op=='+')
{
    ans=no1+no2;
}else if(op=='-')
{
    ans=no1-no2;
}else if(op=='*')
{
    ans=no1*no2;
}else if(op=='/')
{
    ans=no1/no2;
}else
{
    printf("INVALID OPERATOR!!\n");
}

printf("ANSWER=%.2f\n", ans);

return 0;
}
```

Update: thank you for helping! And i will be mindful to copypaste the code instead of posing screenshots in the future,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your question to improve it, for example by copy-pasting text *as text* into it.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: @Styx Could you explain what is this #include<stdio.h>
{

Comment: Two problems: First of all there's no `%ch` format specifier, only `%c` to read single characters; Then `%c` doesn't skip leading white-space like e.g. `%d` does, which means that the `Enter` key that was used for the second number input will be read as a newline into `op`. Which would have been very obvious if you used some *debugging* to check what really happens. So lesson of today: Please learn how to *debug* your programs.

Comment: As a side note, if the `else` block is executed, `ans` will be uninitialized when `printf(“ANSWER=%.2f\n”, ans);` is executed.

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks good, but if you don't copy the code we can not debug to search the error.
I recommend you to debug the code and control what value have the op variable before the if else.

If you copy the code i can try to debug and search the error.

Answer (score -1):

I think your issue is similar to this one [Issues with using if/else statements correctly in C language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358207/issues-with-using-if-else-statements-correctly-in-c-language)

Changing `scanf("%ch",&op);` to `scanf("%c", &op);` might solve your problem.